# How to highlight selected text in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do I add ***span*** tag for selected text in a group of text using Angular JS.

Html:

```html
<div class="container" #contents 
    [attr.contenteditable]="contenteditable"
    (click)="changeContenteditable($event)"
    (mousemove)="showSelectedText($event)">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummied text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
</div>
```

If I select **Lorem Ipsum**, it should wrapped by span element.

How do I achieve this in angular 7

Comment: Please examine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Comment: you want to surround it with HTML element dynamically to your selected text?

Comment: What is the purpose of wrapping it in a `<span>`?

Comment: To highlight the selected text

Comment: @DhamodaranP highlight means? you want to change the color or background of text?